# Colloquial Imperative

Tags: imperative-sentences, causative-have

From time to time I can hear native speakers talk in this way, say, "I will **have** somebody fix this up." While I realize there exist contexts where the sentence is equal in meaning to the sentence "I will find somebody to fix this up.", I do not handle such usage (the boldfaced) well.

So I wish to understand the underlying general rule.

Comment: I would say that the two meanings are not quite equal. Consider the construction "I will have my brother fix this up." This is not equivalent to "I will find my brother to fix this up." Rather, it's equivalent to "I will ask my brother to fix this up." The "have" in this construction, I think, refers to giving an order/making a request. I cannot, however, figure out a nice underlying rule for it.

Comment: Grammatically it's quite similar to "I will **make** somebody fix this up", although the meaning isn't quite the same.

Comment: My attempt (to paraphrase it): "I will get somebody to fix this up."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are normal sentences, however the meanings are different.

> I will **have** somebody fix this up.

implies you will be able to get somebody to do that. It is not a question of "if".

> I will **find** somebody to fix this up.

implies you will look for somebody to do that, but does not directly state someone actually will do that.

Comment: Thank you so much. But how about "I have people told me something"? Does this sentence mean that there were people telling me something?

Comment: @Brian that construction isn't well-formed. The tense of "have" has to match the tense of the subsequent verb. So, "I have people *telling* me something" works, and "I had people *tell* me something" also works, but your example does not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. And that is why I wish to have a general rule~